# go-git "git submodule add <url> <submod>"

Tags: git, go, go-git

## TLDR

I've been scouring the package [Docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-git/go-git/v5) & the official [Examples](https://github.com/go-git/go-git/tree/master/_examples) and can't figure out how to describe adding a submodule using go-git. I'm trying to `git submodule add <url> <submod_name>`, as well as configure it for sparse checkout

## Goal

I want to convert the following list using golang's go-git package. My overall goal is to have a sparsely checked out submodule, which will be from Repo-A, then the overall repo will be for Repo-B. I'm trying to source content from Repo-A, make some edits, and reorganize, then push the results to Repo-B. All that I've included below is the first step, specifically for how to configure this repo+submod from scratch.

✅ `git init`
✅ `git remote add -f <remote_name> <repo_url>`
✅ `git clone --depth=1 --no-checkout <submod_repo_url> <submod_name>`
⬜ `git submodule add <submod_repo_url> <submod_name>`

- Not sure how to call this, I'm thinking it may be possible with edits to the .git directory directly, but that seems messy. Any explanations or suggestions would be appreciated.

⬜ `git submodule absorbgitdirs`

- Not sure if this is even needed, I couldn't find a good description of what it does, but it seems to not cause a problem either way?

⬜ `git -C pinkbrain config core.sparseCheckout true` (NOTE: will only apply to the submodule)

- Not sure how to make this work, since its a .git config, but only for the submodule. Maybe just create a new git.PlainOpen() object and access its working tree that way?

✅ `echo "cir-1" >>.git/modules/<submod_name>/info/sparse-checkout`
✅ `echo "cir-2" >>.git/modules/<submod_name>/info/sparse-checkout`
✅ `git submodule update --force --checkout <submod_name>`

- Not sure if this needs two seperate calls? `Worktree.Pull()` & `Worktree.Pull()`, see code below.

✅ `git pull <remote_name> main`
✅ `git add .`
✅ `git commit -S -m "commit example message"`

## My Questions

1. How do I add a submodule using go-git?
2. Do I need the separate `sw.Checkout(&git.CheckoutOptions` bit? And if so, in what order should I do them?
3. How do I go about configuring a Sparse Checkout in either the main repo OR the submodule?
4. Any thoughts on the `git submodule absorbgitdirs`? Any info about what it is would be appreciated

## What I've got so far (condensed)

**NOTE**: I have more, but it doesn't relate to my questions
This bit is just for the submodule update, since the `go-git` documentation doesn't allow for `--checkout` as part of the `git.PullOptions()`

```golang
// Should be equivalent to : git submodule update --force --checkout <submod_name>
// Get the repo object (could be git.plainOpen() too)
r, err := git.PlainClone(directory, false, &git.CloneOptions{
    <options>
})

// Get the Submodule WorkTree object
w, err := r.Worktree()
sub, err := w.Submodule(submodule)
sr, err := sub.Init()
sw, err := sr.Worktree()

// Get the Update the Submodule
err = sw.Pull(&git.PullOptions{
    <options>
}

// Checkout the submodule, Not sure if this is the right order?
err = sw.Checkout(&git.CheckoutOptions{
    <options>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the current state of [`submodule.go`](https://github.com/go-git/go-git/blob/a50d22d149e9bb5f0b64f5d4c4a8e2cd0a2a51a4/submodule.go) and [`submodule_test.go`](https://github.com/go-git/go-git/blob/db2bc57350561c4368a8d32c42476699b48d2a09/submodule_test.go), adding a submodule does not seem implemented.

That means you would need to use the [`client.go`](https://github.com/go-git/go-git/blob/db2bc57350561c4368a8d32c42476699b48d2a09/plumbing/transport/file/client.go) to `exec.Command` the `git submodule add` yourself.

Comment: Didn't know about client.go, good tip, thank you.